How does String.crypt generate the same hash as BCrypt when given the BCrypt hash as the salt?
I found some code that uses String.crypt to hash passwords (yikes!), so I played around with a way that I could check a password against a BCrypt hash as well as the old String.crypt hashes.
What I found surprised me. The following method seems to work fine for both BCrypt hashes and String.crypt hashes, but I don't know why:
def check_password(password, stored_hash)
  password.crypt(stored_hash) == stored_hash
end

Trying it out:
string_crypt_pass = "mysuperpass".crypt("$1$abasasa")
bcrypt_pass = BCrypt::Password.create("mysuperpass").to_s

check_password("mysuperpass", string_crypt_pass) #true
check_password("mywrongpass", string_crypt_pass) #false

check_password("mysuperpass", bcrypt_pass) #true
check_password("mywrongpass", bcrypt_pass) #false

How does this work?

If those are the results you are experiencing utilizing the exact code posted it appears to be by pure happenstance.
According to String#crypt:

Returns the string generated by calling crypt(3) standard library function...
Please do not use this method any longer. It is legacy; provided only for backward compatibility with ruby scripts in earlier days. It is bad to use in contemporary programs for several reasons:
Behaviour of C’s crypt(3) depends on the OS it is run. The generated string lacks data portability.

Bcrypt only mentions crypt(3) in 2 locations:
https://github.com/bcrypt-ruby/bcrypt-ruby/blob/v3.1.20/ext/mri/crypt_gensalt.c#L17
https://github.com/bcrypt-ruby/bcrypt-ruby/blob/v3.1.20/ext/mri/crypt_blowfish.c#L7
I have run your exact code on multiple OSes and multiple ruby versions (including this online Repl) and I am unable to reproduce your results.
Every time I run this I receive what I would expect which is:
require 'bcrypt'
def check_password(password, stored_hash)
  password.crypt(stored_hash) == stored_hash
end

string_crypt_pass = "mysuperpass".crypt("$1$abasasa")
bcrypt_pass = BCrypt::Password.create("mysuperpass").to_s

check_password("mysuperpass", string_crypt_pass)
#=> true
check_password("mywrongpass", string_crypt_pass)
#=> false
check_password("mysuperpass", bcrypt_pass)
#=> false (or Invalid Argument depending on OS)
check_password("mywrongpass", bcrypt_pass)
#=> false (or Invalid Argument depending on OS)


The last two checks are true, false on my Ubuntu desktop, WSL Ubuntu and our Alpine container for testing. On a colleague's Mac it's false, false, however.

Interestingly, calling "mysuperpass".crypt with just the first 29 chars of the BCrypt hash generates the full BCrypt hash.
